# Is there a method to test whether two shapes can be broadcast in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

Does numpy have a method to test whether to shapes can be broadcast without having to create the arrays? In short, I am looking for a function that provides the following output.

```
can_broadcast((1, 2), (2, 1))  # True
can_broadcast((1, 2), (2, 3))  # False
```

Of course, I can emulate the behaviour using

```
def can_broadcast(s1, s2):
    try:
        np.empty(s1) + np.empty(s2)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

or build my own logic. Is there anything built in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the built-ins work with arrays and not really with only shapes. So, I am not aware of any built-in that could solve it. Here's one I could come up with, basically looking for `singleton` dimensions, i.e. `dimension lengths = 1` and checking if dimension lengths match up and satisfying either one of the criteria gives us `True` for being `broadcastable` -

```
def can_broadcast(s1, s2):
    s1a = np.asarray(s1)
    s2a = np.asarray(s2)
    return ((s1a == 1) | (s2a==1) | (s2a == s1a)).all()
```

Sample runs -

```
In [335]: s1 = (1, 2, 1, 3)
     ...: s2 = (2, 3, 3, 3)
     ...: s3 = (1, 1, 3, 3)
     ...: 

In [336]: print can_broadcast(s1, s2)
     ...: print can_broadcast(s1, s3)
     ...: print can_broadcast(s2, s3)
     ...: 
False
True
True
```